# RequireJs shim: how to prevent duplicate module names inside define() {...}?

Tags: javascript, requirejs

I have the following code:

```
requirejs.config({
    shim: {
        'underscore': {
            exports: '_'
        },
        'backbone': {
            deps: ['underscore', 'jquery'],
            exports: 'Backbone'
        }
    }
});


define(
    ['underscore', 'backbone'],
    function (underscoreLocal, backboneLocal) {

    console.log(underscoreLocal);
    console.log(backboneLocal);
    console.log(_);
    console.log(Backbone);
    }
);
```

All of those console loggings print something. However, I was wondering if it's possible to remove the default exported module name from the modules loaded, ie. to have 'Backbone' and '_' return undefined inside the module? Is it even possible with shim, or am I just thinking this the wrong way?

Answer (score 0):

I think the "_" and "Backbone" symbols in your callback are the ones defined in the global namespace by backbone.js. (they should be window._ or window.Backbone).

As far as I understand it, the "local" versions of synbols are defined by requirejs because you explicitely specified a "exports" variable name.

So I don't think you can prevent the global versions from being defined.